# jQuery DatePicker Range not functioning correctly (jsfiddle included)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/fSrBv/

I'm having an issue here where in my From field I'm able to select a starting date of March 15th, but then in the To field I am able to select a date in the past.  I also have a maxDate defined and I'm able to select beyond that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dates = $( "#dateRangeFrom, #dateRangeTo" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+0d",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "dateRangeFrom" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
```

Example http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max) of the JQuery UI site?